# List of x/y values from a table in excel

Tags: excel

I have a table in excel that contains values in row 1 x1,x2...xn and values in column A y1,y2...yn. I need to populate column A in another spreadsheet with values "x1/y1", "x1/y2"..."xn/yn". Is there a way to do this without creating a script in VBA? Until now I was using just `=Sheet1!A2&"/"Sheet1!&B1` and draging it down and right and then manualy copying results to column A but as the table grows it becomes quite troublesome.

EDIT:
Let me rephrase it so it could be more understandable my Sheet1 looks like

```
   | x1 | x2 | ... | xn | 
y1 |    |    |     |    |
y2 |    |    |     |    |
...
yn |    |    |     |    |
```

now I need to populate column A in Sheet2 so it would look like

```
x1/y1
x1/y2
...
x2/y1
x2/y2
...
xn/yn
```

Is it more understandable now?

Comment: Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). This was very confusing and you should reword it _carefully_ so that we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a couple of `Index` formula to do this

```
=IF(ROW() <= COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A) * COUNTA(Sheet1!$1:$1), INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$1,INT((ROW()-1)/COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A))+2)&"/"&INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,MOD(ROW()-1,COUNTA(Sheet1!$A:$A))+2),"")
```

Starting at `Sheet2!A1` and copy down for at least the number of entries in the table.  Any excess formula will show blanks.